# Generate a serial number based on quantity column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Experts I have a table like this

T1

| Order_no | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |

I need to generate a column 'serial no' having values based on 'qty'

Output needed

| OrderNo | Qty | SerailNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: ok, so what is the logic by which the 'serial number' is derived from the existing data?  And do you need this 'serial number' just in the result set of a query, or do you need to actually put it into a new column in the table?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the specific database so I'll assume you are using PostgreSQL, aren't you?

You can use a Recursive CTE to expand the rows. For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select order_no, qty, 1 as serial_no from t1
 union all
  select order_no, qty, serial_no + 1
  from n
  where serial_no < qty
)
select * from n order by order_no, serial_no
```

Result:

```
 order_no  qty  serial_no 
 --------- ---- --------- 
 1         3    1         
 1         3    2         
 1         3    3         
 2         5    1         
 2         5    2         
 2         5    3         
 2         5    4         
 2         5    5         
 3         1    1         
 4         3    1         
 4         3    2         
 4         3    3
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w7vBeFooMGN7wDafsA2MDD/0).

**EDIT FOR ORACLE**

If you are using Oracle the query changes a bit to:

```
with
n (order_no, qty, serial_no) as (
  select order_no, qty, 1 from t1
 union all
  select order_no, qty, serial_no + 1
  from n
  where serial_no < qty
)
select * from n order by order_no, serial_no
```

Result:

```
 ORDER_NO  QTY  SERIAL_NO 
 --------- ---- --------- 
 1         3    1         
 1         3    2         
 1         3    3         
 2         5    1         
 2         5    2         
 2         5    3         
 2         5    4         
 2         5    5         
 3         1    1         
 4         3    1         
 4         3    2         
 4         3    3
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc9cffa570b6ab67c89f65b5bbc3feb0).

Comment: Thanks. I am using Oracle

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked like a charm. Thanks again for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should first provide the database you're using. Whether it's oracle, Sql Server, PostGreSQL will determine which procedural language to use. It's very likely that you'll need to do this in two steps:
1st: Duplicate the number of rows based on the column `Qty` using a decreasing loop
2nd: You'll need to create a sequential partionned column based on the `Qty` column

Comment: Thanks. I am using Oracle